# Change Azure App API in real time

Tags: api, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-app-api

Prior to migrating from Mobile to App Services I could change node.js APIs in real time. Now changes seem to take an undetermined time to go live. I don't know if they're now being compiled or cached anywhere along the way. Ideally I would like to regain the ability to effect immediate change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, there is a file watcher that watches a subset of the files in your site - when you change one of those files, the site is meant to restart, thus making your change go live.  This is configured in the `web.config` file which is a part of your site.

Make sure that the web.config is configured to watch the files you are interested in.

Restarting the site manually is a backup step that is effective.

Comment: This would unfortunately appear to be the case. As the built in editor consistently saves as you type watching these files would trigger full app restarts. It appears that by migrating from mobile to app services I have lost the granularity to make single scripting changes without affecting the full API suite.